# Twig render empty page with slim framework

Tags: php, twig, slim

I'm using Twig template engine with slim framework 3

i have a simple function inside my controller

```
public function test_twig($request, $response, $args) {
     return $this->view->render($response, "login.phtml");
}
```

When i run this code in the locahost it works perfectly, but i tried it in my server it shows an empty page, very wierd behavior the page has no dynamic variables it's just HTML

I've tried this also :

```
$str = $this->view->fetchFromString('<p>Hi, my name is {{ name }}.</p>', [
        'name' => "oussama"
    ]);
    $response->getBody()->write($str);
    return $response;
```

It worked in the localhost and not in my server ( **i have PHP 5.6 in my server** )

After following the execution i ended up here the compile function can not compile a simple HTML file !!!

/**
     * Compiles a template source code.
     *
     * @return string The compiled PHP source code
     *
     * @throws Twig_Error_Syntax When there was an error during tokenizing, parsing or compiling
     */

```
public function compileSource(Twig_Source $source)
{
    try {

        return $this->compile($this->parse($this->tokenize($source)));
    } catch (Twig_Error $e) {
        $e->setSourceContext($source);
        throw $e;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Twig_Error_Syntax(sprintf('An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("%s").', $e->getMessage()), -1, $source, $e);
    }
}
```

I did follow the code till Twig_Lexer Class Inside the Constructor 
Exactly in this line :

```
   'operator' => $this->getOperatorRegex(),
```

Comment: What's in your error logs?

Comment: i can't find anything in the log , i followed the code execution i found that compileSource function in the core of slim is doing this

Comment: @AdamA  please check my Question Edit

Comment: What Twig version are you using?

Comment: Im using Twig version 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made this working by changing my composer.json requires:

`"slim/twig-view": "2.0",`  change the version to 2.0 since it works with PHP 5.6

Also there was and issue with Eloquent if you use the version "~5.1" it won't work i just putted a strict version "5.4.36" for Database Dependency like this :

```
"illuminate/database": "5.4.36"
```

Answer (score 1):

Twig since version v2.0.0 has required PHP version 7.0 or above. As you have stated that you have PHP 5.6 on the remote server, they will not work together. You can either upgrade to PHP 7 on the remote (if possible), or downgrade twig to v1.35.0, which still supports PHP 5.

Source:

1. https://packagist.org/packages/twig/twig#v2.2.0
2. https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/29bb02dde09ff56291d30f7687eb8696918023af/composer.json

Comment: but bro i'm using https://packagist.org/packages/slim/twig-view 

it's working with php: >=5.5.0 , i tried in another local computer that has 5.6 PHP installed and it worked very normal

Not the twig you mentioned

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention what package the version was referring to. The twig I was referring to is sub-dependency of twig-view. Can you post the twigphp twig version as well as the php version you have locally.

Answer (score 1):

Twig 2.4 requires PHP 7 and above. Your server does not satisfy that requirement and Twig fails.

We need to override the default Twig dependency by setting our own. Add a Twig dependency in your project conposer.json file:

```
"twig/twig":"^1.18"
```

Tell composer to run the new configuration and apply the changes:

```
composer update
```